# Convert Android Matrix values to View transform properties

Tags: android, matrix, view, transform

I have a View which is rotated around the X and Y axis using View.setRotationX and View.setRotationY. I have used View.getMatrix() and modified the values of the Matrix. I would now like to apply the Matrix back to the View but I have not found a good way of doing this without using the legacy Animation API in Android.

[image: illustration of my view]

Basically what i need is to convert the Matrix values to View transformation values.
Example:

```
float[] src = new float[]{0, 0, view.getWidth(), 0, 0, view.getHeight(), view.getWidth(), view.getHeight()};
float[] dst = new float[8];

Matrix matrix = view.getMatrix();
matrix.mapPoints(dst, src);
dst[7] = NEW_Y_COORD_OF_CORNER;
matrix.setPolyToPoly(src, 0, dst, 0, dst.length >> 1);
//The matrix is now changed but the View is not.

So i would like to get rotation and translation of the Matrix to apply it back to the View:

float newRotationX = convertMatrixRotationToViewRotationX(matrix); //method i need
float newRotationY = convertMatrixRotationToViewRotationY(matrix); //method i need

float newTranslationX = convertMatrixRotationToViewTranslationX(matrix); //method i need
float newTranslationY = convertMatrixRotationToViewTranslationY(matrix); //method i need

view.setRotationY(newRotationX);
view.setRotationX(newRotationY);
view.setX(newTranslationX);
view.setY(newTranslationY);
```

This might seem like a far to complex way of transforming the View but I need to do it this way in order to be able to set x,y corner coordinates of the View. For more info of getting the corner coordinates of a way see my previous post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330073/how-to-get-all-4-corner-coordinates-of-a-view-in-android?noredirect=1#comment37672700_24330073

Comment: if you want the other way of mapping use invert()ed Matrix

Comment: Thanks, but I dont see how the inverted matrix will convert the Matrix rotation values to View usable rotation.

Comment: ok,  seems you want something like nonexisting setMatrix method? im afraid you have to do it like you do it now

Comment: i think the easiest is to call Matrix.getValues and to map those nine floats

Comment: Yes, thats the mapping I was hoping some Matrix experts could help with :) I´ll keep trying to figure out how that mapping can be done.